# Multiprocessing using partial() throws ForkingPickler error

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to crawl abstracts from PubMed and filtering them using regex via python. To speed things up, I wanted to use pythons multiprocessing pool.

My code looks like the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial
from typing import List, Tuple

def beautify_abstract(abstract: str, regex: str):
    import re
    result: str = ""
    last_start = 0
    matches = re.finditer(regex, abstract, re.MULTILINE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        result += abstract[last_start:match.start()]
        result += "<b>"
        result += abstract[match.start():match.end()]
        result += "</b>"
        last_start = match.end()
    result += abstract[last_start:]
    return result

def get_doi(pim: str, regex: str):
    from Bio import Entrez
    from Bio.Entrez import efetch
    import re
    from metapub.convert import pmid2doi
    Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"
    print(f"Processing {pim}")
    abstract_handle = efetch(db="pubmed", id=pim, retmode='text', rettype='all')
    abstract = abstract_handle.read()
    abstract_handle.close()

    if re.search(regex, abstract, re.MULTILINE) is not None:
        docsum_handle = efetch(db="pubmed", id=pim, retmode='text', rettype='docsum').read()
        docsum = docsum_handle.read()
        try:
            doi = pmid2doi(pim)
        except:
            doi = "UNKNOWN"
        return f"{doi}"
    return ""

def get_pim_with_regex_list(keywords: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    from Bio import Entrez
    Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"
    searchterm = " ".join(keywords)
    pims = []
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", retstart=0, retmax=0, term=searchterm, idtype="acc")
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    handle.close()
    count = int(record['Count'])
    if count > 100000:
        retmax = 100000
    else:
        retmax = count
    retstart = 0
    while retstart < count:
        handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", retstart=retstart, retmax=retmax, term=searchterm, idtype="acc")
        record = Entrez.read(handle)
        handle.close()
        for pim in record['IdList']:
            pims.append(pim)
        retstart += retmax
    return pims

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keywords = ["keyword1", "keyword2"]
    pim_list = get_pim_with_regex_list(keywords)
    regex = "keyword1 keyword2"

    worker_fn = partial(get_doi, regex=regex)
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    entries = pool.map(worker_fn, pim_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

When I run the given code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tag' and 'attributes'
Process ForkPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 368, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tag' and 'attributes'
```

I did some digging into multiprocessing with python and found out that only python native types are supported as parameters (enforced by the ForkingPickler).
Assuming that `str` is a native type, the code should work... Currently, I am completely lost and have no idea what may be the problem.

As suggested, I uploaded a minimal (sequential) working example [here](https://gist.github.com/JPietrzykTUD/deb48af30554955719d3a7e84d0b7ec2)

Is there any way to fix this problem or at least diagnose the real issue here?

Comment: The cause of the problem is that `worker_fn` is a `partial` and can't be pickled and passed to sub-processes (it only exists in the main process' memory-space) I suggest that you replace the code in your question with a runnable [mre] and maybe someone can help fix that.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is ``partial``? Support for ``multiprocessing`` is one of the main reasons to use ``partial`` instead of ``lambda``. Since partial takes *neither* of the ``2 required positional arguments: 'tag' and 'attributes'``, I would assume the issue is with ``pim_list`` instead.

Comment: @martineau I need to pass the (constant) regex string into the function as well. As depicted [here][1], `partial` does work in combination with `multiprocessing`.

[1]: https://python.omics.wiki/multiprocessing_map

Comment: I may have been wrong about pickling partials...which only underscores the need for a [mre].

Comment: The issue may have something to do with the `from metapub.convert import pmid2doi` and other `import`s in the midst of `get_doi()` (and the related `return f"{pmid2doi(pim)}"` further down).

Comment: I can't run your minimal example because `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'` and I expect several of the other `import`s to also fail if it were to reach to them, so it's of no help (and therefore isn't a useful minimal reproducible example). Just creating one would likely tell you what's wrong…it's a very worthwhile debugging skill to cultivate.

Comment: What exactly do you expect? :D If I get rid of the specific modules, then there isn't much left, is it? If you get such an error, you need to install the modules. This can be done (as you should know regarding your profile) using `pip install metapub` and `pip install biopython`. Depending on your OS you may use your packet manager to install them instead.
Or shall I provide you a docker image which you can pull from dockerhub with every modules in it? Should I provide a walk through on how to install docker? I don't want to sound pricky, but if missing modules are a deal-breaker...

Comment: We expect you to provide a [mcve], *in the question itself*. If external modules are required, clarify which (e.g. it's not apparent that ``biopython`` provides ``Bio``). If calls to external resources, especially those with identification or authentication, are required, fetch the data yourself and provide a literal definition of the result. Along the way of making this example minimal, you will likely find out whether whether ``get_pim_with_regex_list`` actually returns a list of strings and can be removed or whether the issue is from ``biopython``.

Comment: Given the Error message, `pim_list` is likely not a list of strings, but some other class which is having trouble being un-pickled. Pickle typically re-creates an object at the other side by finding the class by name then calling \__new__ to get a new object. unlike normal, \__init__ is not called, and the object's \__dict__ is simply updated with the values sent across via pickle. Here there is a custom class where \__new__ expects extra args which is typical with some custom classmethod constructor patterns, but it makes calling \__new__ on it's own invalid.

Comment: @Aaron This made the trick! When I convert the pim into string everything works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hymir I see you've used type annotations, and actually running mypy would have picked up on this error quite quickly (`get_pim_with_regex_list -> List[str] #not a list of strings`)

Comment: @Aaron I wasn't aware of mypy. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: Mypy is the reason static type hinting was put into official python3 syntax